# Python parse all elements in a specific tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to know how to extract all of the elements under a specific tag.
For example:

```
<div class="text">
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <h2>...</h2>
</div>
```

I would like to get these elements in a list

```
list = ['<h2>...</h2>',
        '<p>...</p>',
        '<p>...</p>',
        '<h2>...</h2>']
```

The reason I need this, I want to know under what category (header) the text is written and extract the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
l = soup.find('div', {'class':'text'}).findChildren()
```